# MySQL: Select rows where `project_id` equals any `project` with specific `user_id`

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This can't be too hard, but I don't know what the term is I'm looking for. I'm sure you guys can help me out. :)

I have a table `tasks` with rows that have a column `project_id`. Each `project_id` refers to (the `id` of) a row in the `projects` table. Each `project` belongs to a certain `user` which is why it has a column `user_id`.

I now want to select all `tasks` from this table where the `project_id` equals any `project` of a certain `user`.

### Or put more simply:

Each TASK belongs to a PROJECT which belongs to a USER.

I want to create a SELECT-statement to receive all TASKS that belong to a specific USER. The only link between each TASK and a USER is through the PROJECT.

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM tasks t
INNER JOIN projects p ON t.project_id = p.project_id
INNER JOIN users    u ON p.user_id    = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = @AcertianUserId
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. If I may ask one more question: is it a symptom of bad database-design that I have to get my rows this way? Should I refactor my database structure so that each task directly holds a user id?

Comment: @Macks - Sure, any time. Not is not, this is the synonym of [normalized database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which is a better database design that the approach you suggested.

Comment: Awesome, this makes me feel real professional. :) Edit: Each project only belongs to one user.

Comment: @Macks = **Note that:** It depends on: Does each task has a separate user that is resposible for it, or it is just the user that is responsible for the whole project? May be it is better in this case if each user is responsible for a specific task to have a user that is fro each task.

Comment: Yeah, each project belongs to only one user. A user can have multiple projects, but each project only has one user.

Comment: @Macks - OK, then, this is fine. Just keep the design you already have. Each project has a user id, not the task. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  tasks.*
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN
  projects ON users.id = projects.user_id
INNER JOIN
  tasks ON projects.id = tasks.project_id
WHERE
  users.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM user u, projet p, task t
 WHERE u.id = p.user_id
   AND p.id = t.project_id
   AND u.id = your_id
```

Or (same result) :

```
SELECT t.*
      FROM user u
     INNER JOIN projet p ON u.id = p.user_id
     INNER JOIN task t ON p.id = t.project_id
     WHERE u.id = your_id
```

Comment: Those `WHERE` conditions should be part of the `JOIN` (for clarity/readability).

Comment: The result is the same as an `inner join`, and it seems that performance as well.

Comment: Also, it makes it easier if you ever convert to a `LEFT JOIN` -- Having the condition in the `WHERE` will effectively make it an `INNER JOIN` (unless you then add another `WHERE` condition to allow for `NULL`, obviously).

Comment: I got this habit from Oracle, where you change in my first query the an `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` simply by adding a `(+)` at the end of the `u.id = p.user_id` restriction (`u.id = p.user_id(+)`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast responses! :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ac21/2/0)

```
select t.*
from tasks t
join projects p on p.id = t.project_id
join users u on u.id = p.user_id
where u.id = 17
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I got it figured out now! :)